# Not able to get text which is not present inside any html tag using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

```
<li>
  <div class="dropdown dropdown--active ">
    <a class="dropdown__trigger dropdown-toggle switch-modes-toggle">
      <span class="ModeIndicator ModeIndicator--test"></span> 
      Test Mode 
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I want to fetch text which says "Test Mode" using selenium. Can any one help me with this. I am new to selenium.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `contains(text())`

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Test Mode')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

The text is in the `<a>` tag

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ModeIndicator']/..")).getText();
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Now I noticed that this text is actually under tag <a>.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use css selector for this.

**CSS SELECTOR :**

```
dropdown__trigger.dropdown-toggle.switch-modes-toggle
```

in code :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("dropdown__trigger.dropdown-toggle.switch-modes-toggle")).getText();
```

However introducing **WebdriverWait** in your code would give more reliability.